# Selenium is returning empty string from Angular website

Tags: angularjs, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs, python-3.5

I am trying to scrape the birthday on http://stats.nba.com/player/#!/76124/career/ (Under where it says 'Born') but the birthday is being generated dynamically, so BeautifulSoup can't get it.

[image: Image of the NBA.com player profile that Im scraping]

I am trying Selenium and here is the code I use:

```
driver.get(url)
sleep(5)
e = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('player-stats__stat-value')
for a in e:
    print(a.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
driver.close()
```

It prints out blank lines. This is what the html looks like if I go to Inspect->Network->XHR->Response:

```
<span class="player-stats__stat-value" itemprop="birthDate">{{ playerInfo.BIRTHDATE | date:'M/d/yy' }}</span>
```

Can Selenium return the actual value of the `{{ playerInfo.BIRTHDATE | date:'M/d/yy' }}` and, if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

```
e = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='summary']//span[@class='player-stats__stat-value' and @itemprop='birthDate']")
for a in e:
    print(a.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
driver.close()
```

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('http://stats.nba.com/player/#!/76124/career/')
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
e = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='summary']//span[@class='player-stats__stat-value' and @itemprop='birthDate']")
for a in e:
    print(a.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
driver.close()
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: No, it prints empty lines - same as what I had before.

Comment: Apologies, I am not aware of `scrape` but I tried to extract the text `3/26/56` from the node through the updated code block within my Answer. It worked well at my side. Can you guide me what exactly you do to `scrape`? Thanks

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much! I was using phantomJS not Chrome webdriver. Really appreciate it. I have to do this thousands of times, so I am wondering if you know how to get it to work for the phantomJS driver, because the Chrome window opening and closing is a bit much (or if you know a Chrome workaround). If not, thanks so much! Appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

I have 3 angilar tabs each containing a grid (p-table). GetText() returns blank and getAttribute("innerHTML") returns the value of the corresponding cell from grid in the adjacent tab sheet

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and fix it, or just post it as a comment to the question.